# eval variable=command in the background

Tags: shell-script, background-process, eval

I have the following code

```
for name in a b c d; do
    for i in {01..12}; do
        eval test_${name}_{i}=`some command`
    done
done
```

I am trying to do the assignments in the background but it doesn't work in a shell script like below:

```
for name in a b c d; do
    for i in {01..12}; do
        eval test_${name}_{i}=`some command` & 
    done
done
wait
echo $test_a_01
```

I got empty value

Comment: It will never produce `$test_a_1`, but `$test_a_01`.

Comment: Thanks i have edited my post sorry it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a value like that. The background process has to run in another process, otherwise it couldn't be independent of the main shell. And as such, it can't store the values back "up" to the main shell.

Instead, you could store the outputs to a file (or several files).

```
for name in a b c d; do
    for i in {1..12}; do
        printf "test_${name}_${i}=%s\n" "$(some command "$name" "$i")" >> output & 
    done
done
wait
```

and if you want them in shell variables, you can read them back from the file. Here, using an associative array in Bash:

```
declare -A outputs
while IFS== read -r key value; do
    outputs["$key"]="$value"
done < output
echo ${outputs[test_b_7]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Background commands run in a subshell. Subshell commands do not affect the environment (or internal variables) of the parent shell.